# Excel formula: Buscar penúltima fecha (posición relativa variable)

Tags: excel

tengo este objetivo:
Traer con fórmula la penúltima fecha de cada cliente:

```
A               B
Fecha de compra cliente
01/03/2018  5
02/03/2018  7
05/03/2018  7
**06/03/2018    5**   'fecha objetivo
08/03/2018  7
**12/03/2018    7**   'fecha objetivo
15/03/2018  5
15/03/2018  5
16/03/2018  7
```

En otra hoja tengo el listado de clientes sin repetidos y en la columna siguiente estarían los resultados. Me enfrento con el inconveniente de que la posición relativa es variable y no me funcionaría una variante que encontré de la fórmula sumaproducto con k.esimo.mayor porque en el caso del cliente 5 sale el mismo resultado que la última fecha por estar repetido el dato, Ej:

```
A                   B
Etiquetas de fila   Penultima Fecha
1   00/01/1900
4   26/03/2018
5   15/03/2018
6   15/03/2018
7   12/03/2018
```

En B4 tengo:

```
=SUMAPRODUCTO(K.ESIMO.MAYOR(($A$2:$A$7231=A4)*$B$2:$B$7231;2))
```

Pero me lanza el 15/03/2018 y lo que se ocupa sería el 06/03/2018

Por favor gurús, un poco de ayuda para este simple mortal.
Un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ha sido fácil, pero creo que te puede servir. Mi fórmula es matricial, así que tendrás que meter la fórmula con <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. La fórmula es:

`=K.ESIMO.MAYOR(SI($B$3:$B$11=D3;$A$3:$A$11);1+CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($B$3:$B$11;D3;$A$3:$A$11;MAX(SI($B$3:$B$11=D3;$A$3:$A$11))))`

Te pongo un pantallazo de cómo he simulado el ejemplo. En mi caso, mi rango de fechas es `A3:A11` y el rango del nº de cliente es `B3:B11`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Básicamente, la fórmula mira el 2º valor máximo por cliente (la penúltima fecha). Pero por otro lado, cuenta el nº de veces que se repite el valor máximo (la fecha más reciente). Si la fecha más reciente está aparece N veces, la fórmula te devolverá la 1+N fecha más alta. Por ejemplo, si la fecha más reciente del cliente 5 aparece 4 veces, a tí te interesa la quinta, porque es el 2º valor único más alto. La fórmula es matricial porque hay que jugar con criterios (el nº de cliente) y tu rango de fechas puede tener duplicados. Pero espero que te pueda servir. Ya me contarás.

Comment: Genio!!! eres un capo, muchisimas gracias mis respetos.

Comment: Gracias!!! Si te sirvió, por favor, marca la respuesta como correcta, para que la pregunta aparezca como respondida. Gracias!